# How can I "advancedly" filter the questions list according to my tags?

Tags: support, tag-watching, ignored-tags

That is, using the complex criteria like "hide (collapse) questions with 'ignored' tags unless they have an 'interesting' tag"?

I looked through the similar questions, but they only explain how to hide questions with 'ignored' tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for currently isn't possible.

A decision had to be made about what to do with questions that have both an interesting *and* an ignored tag. It was decided that the question should be *ignored* in this case. Of course, this doesn't make people like yourself who want the opposite behaviour very happy.

IIRC, there are a few feature requests floating around Meta that deal with this type of thing by taking into account the number of interesting/ignored tags on a question.